# Combining two rows into one row in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in working with R and need some help. Sorry if this question was answered before.

1) I have following `data.frame`

```
ID  test
"1" "testA" 
"1" "testB" 
"2" "testA" 
"2" "testB" 
"3" "testA"
"4" "testB"
```

The `data.frame` provides information on whether test A and/or test B was performed in test subjects

2) I would like to combine the individual rows with the same ID into one single row without losing the information in "test". This is the desired output:

```
ID testA testB
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     1     0
4     0     1
```

with `1 = yes` and `0 = no`

Comment: For this only `table(df)` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solution (in a deleted comment) with `reshape()`:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
ID test
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
3 A
4 B
"), header = TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "character"))

dat$value <- 1
dat <- reshape(dat, idvar = "test", timevar = "ID", direction = "wide")
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
dat <- t(dat[, 2:5])
dimnames(dat) <- list(1:4, c("A", "B"))
dat
```

Suggested solution (in a comment by @RonakShah) with `table()`:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
ID test
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
3 A
4 B
"), header = TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "character"))

table(dat)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!